# ReactNative + Expo | App crashes when Algolia's InstantSearch renders

Tags: react-native, expo, algolia

using ‍`react-instantsearch-native‍`

`import { InstantSearch } from 'react-instantsearch-native'`

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.navigator.userAgent.includes')

This error is located at:

```
in InstantSearch (created by wrappedComponent)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by wrappedComponent)
```

This is how the code looks like:

```
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName={algoliaIndexName}>                        
    </InstantSearch>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Hello. Could you include some code on what have you tried? The error message seems to refer you're using web (React) API instead of React Native

Comment: `return (<View style={{ flex: 1 }}><InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName={algoliaIndexName}>          
    </InstantSearch></View>);`

@SamuliHakoniemi

Comment: this is a bug in React InstantSearch, fixed by https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/pull/3184

Comment: The fix has been released in 6.15.0, thanks for your help all!